# Current customer doesnot have an active cart

Tags: magento2, checkout, shopping-cart

I'm using Magento 2.4.3-p2 version, now I'm facing a strange error at the checkout page. When I click on place order button, it says Something went wrong and  Current customer doesnot have an active cart message but the order is placed.

Tried switching to Luma, disabled few modules but it did not worked.

[image]

Comment: Anybody facing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to happen when an order notification e-mail generates an error.

Check the email variables.